# PHP - retrieving and parsing this JSON file

Tags: php, json

I'm looking for a way to access this JSON file data. What I'm interested in is to extract the property named `documentjsonblob`, as below.

```
object(Quadrem\Model\Order)[201]
  protected '_dateCreated' => null
  protected '_buyerCode' => null
    array (size=2)
      2415 => 
        array (size=23)
          '@storeid' => string '813' (length=3)
          '@active' => string '1' (length=1)
          '@created' => string '2013-11-25 12:28:21' (length=19)
          'documentjsonblob' => string '{"HEAD":{"ORDERSEQUENCE":"0","TOTAL_TAX":7.9,"TOTAL_AMOUNT":86.9,"NUMBER":"AKMon3","TYPE":"NB","TYPE_NAME":"Standard PO","SUPPLIER":"0000002122","CREATED":"2013-04-29T12:00:00Z","CONTRACT_NUMBER":"","EXTERNAL_REFERENCE":"","CONTACT_PERSON":"Caroline Howlett","COMMENT":[""],"CURRENCY":"AUD","DELIVERY_TERMS":"DeliveryCondition|","PAYMENT_TERMS":[{"TEXT1":"21st day of next month after receipt"}],"NET_VALUE":79.0,"DELIVERY_ADDRESS":{"NAME_1":"KGTP FACILITY","NAME_2":"GAS TREATMENT PLANT","NAME_3":"KGPF","POSTAL_CODE":"6714","CITY":"Karratha","STREET":"Withnell Bay","REGION":"AUWA","REGION_NAME":"AUWA","COUNTRY":"AU"}]}' (length=3029)
          'documenttype' => string 'PO' (length=2)
      1890 => 
        array (size=23)
          '@storeid' => null
          '@active' => null
```

I'm not quite sure which kind of an encoded JSON file this is by the way it looks. Would appreciate it if somebody could help.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's just a PHP object.

Comment: if you want to reed this data in php, then you can use json_decode()

Comment: If you have that in a file, I don't think you can parse it easily. It looks like the output of `var_dump()`.

Comment: it is the output of var_dump() to be exact. How could I turn it into an object that I can access?

Comment: Why do you want to first dumpp and then re-read that data? Anyways: you can use serialization for that, but you have to do it. Just dumping is something else. Take a look at phps own serialization functions `serialize()` & `unserialize()` or the more general JSON perdants `json_encode()` & `json_decode()`... That is: read their documentation, it contains good examples too.

Answer (score 0):

Since in the comment you have mentioned it is the out put of `var_dump` and you want to get `documentjsonblob`, let's follow this:

- On first line you have `object(Quadrem\Model\Order)[201]`, that means you var_dumped an **object**, say `$my_obj`
- On line four `array (size=2)` says you have an array, and what you need is located in the **first element** of the array, so `$my_obj[0]`
- `$my_obj[0]` holds an associative array, and the desired index is `documentjsonblob`, so we can get the **String** representation as:

  `$my_arr = $my_obj[0];
  $json_str = $my_arr['documentjsonblob'];`

Now `$json_str` holds the String representation, to convert it to an PHP object:

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
```

So now `$json_obj` holds the object you want.